# Why did my AsyncValue provider in Riverpod returned as loading state endlessly?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I'm currently learning Riverpod and I'm trying to implementing Riverpod inside my BottomSheetModal. Which will triggered based on QRcode Scanner. Then upon scanned, i want it to retrieve the data from Firestore and present it to user inside the modal.

*part of Scanned_Shipment_Modal.dart*

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: Future.value(capture),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var dateNow = DateTime.now();
                  var shipmentoutdataref = ref.watch(getShipmentOutDataProvider(
                    shipmentTrack: barcode.barcodes.first.rawValue!,
                    dateNow: dateNow,
                  ));
                  return shipmentoutdataref.when(
                      data: (data) {
                        debugPrint(data.toString());
                        return Wrap(
                          children: [
                            ScannedShipmentOutModal(shipmentoutdataref: data)
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                      error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorPopup().errorPopup(
                          context, "Error", "No Da"),
                      loading: () {
                        return const LoadingCircle(
                          height: 200,
                          width: 200,
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return ErrorPopup()
                  .errorPopup(context, "Error", "No Data Avaliable");
                }
              });
        });
```

However, My `AsyncValue.when` object keep returning as endless state of loading instead of returning data. I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong in regard of the provider code part, but after hours of searching google and debugging. i couldn't determined the reason as to why it won't load. So i could use some fresh eyes here.

*scanned_shipment_out_provider.dart*

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:logistec/models/Firebase/model/firestore_data_models.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'scanned_shipment_out_provider.g.dart';

@riverpod
Future<FirestoreShipmentOutData?> getShipmentOutData(GetShipmentOutDataRef ref,
    {required String shipmentTrack, required DateTime dateNow}) async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String getformattedDate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(dateNow);
  var dataref =
      firestore.collection("DHL_Service_RecheckData").doc(getformattedDate);
  var data = await dataref.get();
  try {
    var dataList = data.get(shipmentTrack);
    return FirestoreShipmentOutData.fromJSON(dataList);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I knew that FutureBuilder widget will work just fine in this case. but i really want to understand Riverpod and thus, attempted to use it as much as i can. Plus it seems more readable for me. And so i'd appreciated the explanation of what i did wrong and how to corrected it. Thank you!

(Not sure it's related since according to many threads, they are there just to support the main files. but just in case, here's generated code from build_runner)

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'scanned_shipment_out_provider.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// RiverpodGenerator
// **************************************************************************

String _$getShipmentOutDataHash() =>
    r'63e7aae52cf51686a22aad856f1c414e4ec35a2f';

/// Copied from Dart SDK
class _SystemHash {
  _SystemHash._();

  static int combine(int hash, int value) {
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = 0x1fffffff & (hash + value);
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = 0x1fffffff & (hash + ((0x0007ffff & hash) << 10));
    return hash ^ (hash >> 6);
  }

  static int finish(int hash) {
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = 0x1fffffff & (hash + ((0x03ffffff & hash) << 3));
    // ignore: parameter_assignments
    hash = hash ^ (hash >> 11);
    return 0x1fffffff & (hash + ((0x00003fff & hash) << 15));
  }
}

typedef GetShipmentOutDataRef
    = AutoDisposeFutureProviderRef<FirestoreShipmentOutData?>;

/// See also [getShipmentOutData].
@ProviderFor(getShipmentOutData)
const getShipmentOutDataProvider = GetShipmentOutDataFamily();

/// See also [getShipmentOutData].
class GetShipmentOutDataFamily
    extends Family<AsyncValue<FirestoreShipmentOutData?>> {
  /// See also [getShipmentOutData].
  const GetShipmentOutDataFamily();

  /// See also [getShipmentOutData].
  GetShipmentOutDataProvider call({
    required String shipmentTrack,
    required DateTime dateNow,
  }) {
    return GetShipmentOutDataProvider(
      shipmentTrack: shipmentTrack,
      dateNow: dateNow,
    );
  }

  @override
  GetShipmentOutDataProvider getProviderOverride(
    covariant GetShipmentOutDataProvider provider,
  ) {
    return call(
      shipmentTrack: provider.shipmentTrack,
      dateNow: provider.dateNow,
    );
  }

  static const Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? _dependencies = null;

  @override
  Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? get dependencies => _dependencies;

  static const Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? _allTransitiveDependencies = null;

  @override
  Iterable<ProviderOrFamily>? get allTransitiveDependencies =>
      _allTransitiveDependencies;

  @override
  String? get name => r'getShipmentOutDataProvider';
}

/// See also [getShipmentOutData].
class GetShipmentOutDataProvider
    extends AutoDisposeFutureProvider<FirestoreShipmentOutData?> {
  /// See also [getShipmentOutData].
  GetShipmentOutDataProvider({
    required this.shipmentTrack,
    required this.dateNow,
  }) : super.internal(
          (ref) => getShipmentOutData(
            ref,
            shipmentTrack: shipmentTrack,
            dateNow: dateNow,
          ),
          from: getShipmentOutDataProvider,
          name: r'getShipmentOutDataProvider',
          debugGetCreateSourceHash:
              const bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product')
                  ? null
                  : _$getShipmentOutDataHash,
          dependencies: GetShipmentOutDataFamily._dependencies,
          allTransitiveDependencies:
              GetShipmentOutDataFamily._allTransitiveDependencies,
        );

  final String shipmentTrack;
  final DateTime dateNow;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is GetShipmentOutDataProvider &&
        other.shipmentTrack == shipmentTrack &&
        other.dateNow == dateNow;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    var hash = _SystemHash.combine(0, runtimeType.hashCode);
    hash = _SystemHash.combine(hash, shipmentTrack.hashCode);
    hash = _SystemHash.combine(hash, dateNow.hashCode);

    return _SystemHash.finish(hash);
  }
}
// ignore_for_file: unnecessary_raw_strings, subtype_of_sealed_class, invalid_use_of_internal_member, do_not_use_environment, prefer_const_constructors, public_member_api_docs, avoid_private_typedef_functions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite an expert on Riverpod, but I would say that whenever your

```dart
var shipmentoutdataref = ref.watch(getShipmentOutDataProvider(
                    shipmentTrack: barcode.barcodes.first.rawValue!,
                    dateNow: dateNow,
                  ));
```

receives data, the builder is called again to build the loaded data. However, in this case your `shipmentoutdataref` changes in the process, as dateNow will be different and thus you end up with a different provider (i.e. your shipmentoutdataref is no longer the same.). This new provider will be in the loading state, and once *it* has received data, the same sequence occurs. You might be able to fix this by moving the dateNow to somewhere within the providers as opposed to the 'initializer', if possible.

Comment: huh, i did what you said and moved dateNow variable from inside the widget to my provider and it fixed the issues. Thank you so much! So from my understanding. basically DateTime.now() will re-run itself constantly, thus making ref.watch keep firing the loading state nonstop then? Am i understand the issue correctly?

Comment: You're not quite there yet. Your getShipmentOutDataProvider is a Family provider (https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family). This means that it is a provider that can take extra arguments (in your old code: the shipmentTrack and the dateNow). The idea of these providers is that their return value might be different based on these arguments, but are the same if the arguments stay the same. If you call the provider with the same arguments, it will remember that you called it before and use the same data, but with different arguments it will be a whole different provider.

Comment: In your FutureBuilder, every time the builder is called, the dateNow will be created again (so not every time the time changes, but every time the widget is build again), and so the arguments of your familyprovider change. Therefore it will create a provider that is different from the provider from an earlier build, and thus it will still be in a loading state. By moving the dateNow inside the provider, the arguments do not change with every widget build, so it will 'remember' the provider from earlier and use its finished state.